# bash: /: Is a directory inside curl command

Tags: bash, curl, post, path, webdriver

Im trying to post data with curl command. My data is a path to some file (string type). My command looks like this:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"value":
["C:/Users/foo/bar/image.jpg"]}' http://<Some url>/wd/hub/session/1
```

Im getting the following error:

```
bash: /: Is a directory
```

This command worked when posting any other string (e.g "Hello world").

How can get this working?

Comment: The command you posted should work, what's in `<Some URL>` ?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Its my IP address (I'm testing locally)

Comment: I don't think the error is coming from that `curl` command. If it were, the error would begin with `curl:`, not `bash:`.

Comment: Do you have any input or output redirection on that command, but you didn't show it in the question?

Comment: Are you actually using angle-brackets around the IP address (i.e. are you using `http://10.0.0.5/wd/hub/session/1` or `http://<10.0.0.5>/wd/hub/session/1`)? Also, have you redefined the `curl` command in any way (what does `type curl` show)?

Comment: @Barmar I'm running from a git bash. Command works with any other string. No other output is shown. What do you mean by input redirection?

Comment: Input and output redirection is ending a command with `< filename` or `> filename`

Comment: @GordonDavisson that was it! curl was redefined in some alias file! I removed the alias and now it works! Thank you so much man!

Answer (score 0):

(credit: @GordonDavisson)

```
type curl
```

printed suspicious output.

I opened my alias file (where I save my custom commands) and found out curl was aliased, meaning its functionality was overridden.

Removing the alias and saving did the magic:-)